# Rails defined which fields will return from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model in rails, for example Post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :title
      t.text :answer
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What i want to do is control which fields returning by default when i am query my model, so for example lets say i want to return only the title field in every query, **without using select**. i am coming from laravel and there i can do this. How i can do this in rails?

Comment: try this : default_scope -> {select("your_field_name")}

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ActiveRecord` `default_scope` that will be added with all the queries be default.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { select('id, title') }
end
```

Comment: This is not working, i am getting all the fields and id: null

Comment: @user233232 if you want id along with title you can give as comma separated string. ie  `default_scope { select('id, title') }`

Comment: @VishnuAtrai you should pass multiple arguments, i.e. `select('id', 'title')` or `select(:id, :title)`